# what does this error mean while sending smtp mail from IIS 7 server through php script

Tags: php, email, iis-7, smtp

I am getting this error after submitting contact form data. Remote Desktop server is IIS 7. Php code to send mail using smtp authentication has been written for you to know my fault better.

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in C:\MYL_SERVER\mydemowebsite.com\mail.php on line 2
```

my mail code is mentioned below:

```
   <?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


  $myname=$_POST['myname'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $contact=$_POST['mob'];

  // require_once "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\pear\Mail.php";
    require_once "Mail.php";


   $from = "$myname <$email>";
   $to = " <info@domain.com>";

    $subject = "Contact Details ";
    $body = "Intereted User Name: $myname\n\n Email id: $email\n\nContact No.: $contact\n";

   $host = "smtp.live.com";
   $port = 25;
   $username = "info@domain.com";
   $password = "mypassword for above mail id";



     $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password,'port' => $port));

  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
      } else {
      header('location:index.php');

    }
  ?>
```

Below is my mail.php code

```
    <?php
  /**
     *  PEAR's Mail:: interface.
     *
     * PHP versions 4 and 5
     *
     * LICENSE:
     *
     * Copyright (c) 2002-2007, Richard Heyes
     * All rights reserved.
     *
     * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
     * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
     * are met:
     *
     * o Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
     *   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     * o Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     *   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
     *   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
     * o The names of the authors may not be used to endorse or promote
     *   products derived from this software without specific prior written
     *   permission.
     *
     * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
     * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
     * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
     * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
     * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
     * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
     * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
     * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
     * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
     * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
     * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
     *
     * @category    Mail
     * @package     Mail
     * @author      Chuck Hagenbuch <chuck@horde.org>
     * @copyright   1997-2010 Chuck Hagenbuch
     * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php New BSD License
     * @version     CVS: $Id: Mail.php 294747 2010-02-08 08:18:33Z clockwerx $
     * @link        http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/
      */

   require_once 'PEAR.php';

  /**
  * PEAR's Mail:: interface. Defines the interface for implementing
  * mailers under the PEAR hierarchy, and provides supporting functions
  * useful in multiple mailer backends.
  *
  * @access public
  * @version $Revision: 294747 $
  * @package Mail
  */
  class Mail
   {
      /**
      * Line terminator used for separating header lines.
      * @var string
      */
        var $sep = "\r\n";

      /**
      * Provides an interface for generating Mail:: objects of various
      * types
      *
      * @param string $driver The kind of Mail:: object to instantiate.
     * @param array  $params The parameters to pass to the Mail:: object.
     * @return object Mail a instance of the driver class or if fails a PEAR Error
     * @access public
     */
     function &factory($driver, $params = array())
    {
         $driver = strtolower($driver);
        @include_once 'Mail/' . $driver . '.php';
         $class = 'Mail_' . $driver;
           if (class_exists($class)) {
          $mailer = new $class($params);
           return $mailer;
         } else {
         return PEAR::raiseError('Unable to find class for driver ' . $driver);
       }
   }

     /**
     * Implements Mail::send() function using php's built-in mail()
     * command.
     *
     * @param mixed $recipients Either a comma-seperated list of recipients
     *              (RFC822 compliant), or an array of recipients,
     *              each RFC822 valid. This may contain recipients not
     *              specified in the headers, for Bcc:, resending
     *              messages, etc.
     *
     * @param array $headers The array of headers to send with the mail, in an
     *              associative array, where the array key is the
     *              header name (ie, 'Subject'), and the array value
     *              is the header value (ie, 'test'). The header
     *              produced from those values would be 'Subject:
     *              test'.
     *
     * @param string $body The full text of the message body, including any
     *               Mime parts, etc.
     *
     * @return mixed Returns true on success, or a PEAR_Error
     *               containing a descriptive error message on
     *               failure.
     *
     * @access public
     * @deprecated use Mail_mail::send instead
     */
       function send($recipients, $headers, $body)
       {
           if (!is_array($headers)) {
            return PEAR::raiseError('$headers must be an array');
       }

        $result = $this->_sanitizeHeaders($headers);
         if (is_a($result, 'PEAR_Error')) {
           return $result;
        }

          // if we're passed an array of recipients, implode it.
             if (is_array($recipients)) {
             $recipients = implode(', ', $recipients);
        }

         // get the Subject out of the headers array so that we can
        // pass it as a seperate argument to mail().
           $subject = '';
           if (isset($headers['Subject'])) {
             $subject = $headers['Subject'];
             unset($headers['Subject']);
         }

          // flatten the headers out.
            list(, $text_headers) = Mail::prepareHeaders($headers);

         return mail($recipients, $subject, $body, $text_headers);
       }

   /**
    * Sanitize an array of mail headers by removing any additional header
    * strings present in a legitimate header's value.  The goal of this
    * filter is to prevent mail injection attacks.
    *
    * @param array $headers The associative array of headers to sanitize.
    *
    * @access private
    */
      function _sanitizeHeaders(&$headers)
       {
         foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
              $headers[$key] =
                preg_replace('=((<CR>|<LF>|0x0A/%0A|0x0D/%0D|\\n|\\r)\S).*=i',
                         null, $value);
        }
   }

/**
 * Take an array of mail headers and return a string containing
 * text usable in sending a message.
 *
 * @param array $headers The array of headers to prepare, in an associative
 *              array, where the array key is the header name (ie,
 *              'Subject'), and the array value is the header
 *              value (ie, 'test'). The header produced from those
 *              values would be 'Subject: test'.
 *
 * @return mixed Returns false if it encounters a bad address,
 *               otherwise returns an array containing two
 *               elements: Any From: address found in the headers,
 *               and the plain text version of the headers.
 * @access private
 */
     function prepareHeaders($headers)
      {
         $lines = array();
          $from = null;

          foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
              if (strcasecmp($key, 'From') === 0) {
                 include_once 'Mail/RFC822.php';
                 $parser = new Mail_RFC822();
                  $addresses = $parser->parseAddressList($value, 'localhost', false);
                   if (is_a($addresses, 'PEAR_Error')) {
                     return $addresses;
                  }

                   $from = $addresses[0]->mailbox . '@' . $addresses[0]->host;

            // Reject envelope From: addresses with spaces.
            if (strstr($from, ' ')) {
                return false;
            }

            $lines[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
        } elseif (strcasecmp($key, 'Received') === 0) {
            $received = array();
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $line) {
                    $received[] = $key . ': ' . $line;
                }
            }
            else {
                $received[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
            }
            // Put Received: headers at the top.  Spam detectors often
            // flag messages with Received: headers after the Subject:
            // as spam.
            $lines = array_merge($received, $lines);
        } else {
            // If $value is an array (i.e., a list of addresses), convert
            // it to a comma-delimited string of its elements (addresses).
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = implode(', ', $value);
            }
            $lines[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
        }
        }

    return array($from, join($this->sep, $lines));
    }

/**
 * Take a set of recipients and parse them, returning an array of
 * bare addresses (forward paths) that can be passed to sendmail
 * or an smtp server with the rcpt to: command.
 *
 * @param mixed Either a comma-seperated list of recipients
 *              (RFC822 compliant), or an array of recipients,
 *              each RFC822 valid.
 *
 * @return mixed An array of forward paths (bare addresses) or a PEAR_Error
 *               object if the address list could not be parsed.
 * @access private
 */
      function parseRecipients($recipients)
     {
         include_once 'Mail/RFC822.php';

        // if we're passed an array, assume addresses are valid and
        // implode them before parsing.
          if (is_array($recipients)) {
             $recipients = implode(', ', $recipients);
       }

    // Parse recipients, leaving out all personal info. This is
    // for smtp recipients, etc. All relevant personal information
    // should already be in the headers.
    $addresses = Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList($recipients, 'localhost', false);

    // If parseAddressList() returned a PEAR_Error object, just return it.
    if (is_a($addresses, 'PEAR_Error')) {
        return $addresses;
    }

    $recipients = array();
    if (is_array($addresses)) {
        foreach ($addresses as $ob) {
            $recipients[] = $ob->mailbox . '@' . $ob->host;
            }
         }

    return $recipients;
     }

     }
```

Comment: what edit should I make in mail.php?

Comment: post your Mail.php file's code.

Comment: I have posted it please check